# Rails 4 - Nested resources - REST API render json error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rest

I have these routes:

`resources :championships do
    resources :rounds do
        resources :games
    end
end`

When I try to insert a game by POST I got this error:

`NoMethodError in GamesController#create
undefined method 'games' for nil:NilClass`

But the data is inserted correctly!

Part of GamesController:

```
before_filter :load_round

def create
    @game = @round.new(model_params)

    if @game.save
        render json: @game, status: :created, location: @round
    else
        render json: @game.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
end

private

    def model_params
        params.require(:game).permit(:team_1_id, :team_2_id)
    end

    def load_round
        @round = Round.find(params[:round_id])
    end
```

PS: I am using the same logic to include Rounds inside a Championship whith no problem

Comment: Do you use any serializer? What happens if you remove the `location: @round` ?

Comment: @DimitriJorge I remove the location and it works fine!
What is this location for?

Answer (score 0):

As seen in comment, the issue here comes from the `location: @round`.

As stated in the [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html), the `location` param sets the **HTTP Location header**.

It takes an **URL** as value. It should work if you change this to use the rails url helpers `location: round_url(@round)`, if your *round* route is not namespaced or nested.